# Reading "\n" character in python failing

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a `\n` character from the user, but it's no working.
Here is my code:

```
op = raw_input("Hit enter to continue!")

if op == '\n':
 #run code
```

However, when I hit enter the code inside the `if condition` doesn't run. It's like op is not `\n`, though I've just hit enter.

Comment: `raw_input` does not return the new line character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From raw_input docstring: "Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped."

So just change to

```
if op == '':
 #run code
```

Answer (score 4):

`raw_input` removes the `\n` from the end of the input. If you want to check a string's blank, ie: the user has just used enter... just use `if not op`.

You can also debug this yourself quite easily, for instance:

```
op = raw_input('enter something: ') # hit only enter
print repr(op) # it's a blank string
```

Comment: +1 for showing how to do the debugging.  Teach a man to fish...

Answer (score 1):

Nope, `raw_input` (Python 2.x) or `input` (Python 3.x) does not return the last NewLine (`\n`) character since that is how it knows that you have *finished* entering the input.

If you want to check for empty user input (simple enter), you could do

```
if not op:
    # code
```

or

```
if op == "":
    # code
```

The `if not op:` version is a general purpose statement since the boolean evaluation from `not` returns `True` for all of these -

1. Empty "iterables" - `''`, `[]`, `{}`, `()`
2. boolean "False" - `False`, `0`, `0.0`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check for a blank input is to first strip then test truthiness:

```
if not op.strip():
   #code
```

You need to call strip() because blank spaces are still `True`:

```
>>> s
'  '
>>> bool(s)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pause a python 2.x script until the user hits enter you can just use:

```
raw_input("Hit enter to continue!")
```

Then regardless of what is inputted the script will continue with whatever code follows. I tend to make a function for it (one called "prompt" for example) so that if I want to edit the prompt or behavior I can just edit the function, so:

```
def prompt():
    raw_input("Hit enter to continue!")
```

Then in your script when you want to pause until the user inputs anything use:

```
prompt()
```